# TFS How to merge two development branches together?

Tags: tfs

I have reviewed the web attempting to find a solution to this.  I have two development branches and one main branch (production).  I need to merge my two development branches together and then merge that joined dev branch to live (main).  When I attempt to merge the two dev branches together the only target branch that I get is live/main.  Any ideas on how to do this?  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click the "browse" button and then browse to the branch that you want to merge to. It will give you a warning in the merge window that you are about to do a baseless merge.

This really isn't the best way to do this, however. Merge both branches (separately) into the main branch, then pull main into each development branch. Then everything is up to date, you minimize your merge clashes (you'll know exactly where the clash came from), and you don't have to do a baseless merge (which will create a permanent relationship between your two development branches).

Comment: Thanks, I found a document that basically told me to do what you just did. Here. :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668955.aspx  Thanks for your answer.